# Logging External SIP INVITE with IoT Modems (EC25)

Tags: sip, modem, diagnostics, qualcomm, quectel

I'm on a journey of learning how mobile carriers communicate with IoT devices. I set a goal of capturing the incoming SIP INVITE from the carrier. I haven't been able to find any examples online of it being collected on an IoT module like the Quectel EC25. The IoT module I have is built around VOIP networks, and from what I understand it should be receiving this information if it can receive a phone call. I've been able to send and receive phone calls with AT commands from this module. It has to be possible, right? Has anyone been able to capture the SIP INVITE for voice calls? I've tried using qcsuper and scat, but wasn't successful.

Answer (score 0):

ATD+Phone number can make a dila, but need insure your module is inserted SIM card, and the SIM card is support call.